# Why is the Formula property necessary?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been wondering what the purpose of the *Formula property* is in VBA since we can get the exact same output in Excel using the same code without the the said property.

For example :

```
Sub myformula()

Range("f3").Formula = "=sum(b6+h9)"

End Sub
```

produces the same results as

```
Sub myformula()

Range("f3") = "=sum(b6+h9)"

End Sub
```

Is there a specific scenario in which using this property becomes important and just typing out the formula as a value might not work?

Comment: You can hope Excel correctly guesses that what you enter as a `Value` is a formula, or you can ensure that Excel knows that what you enter as a `Formula` is a formula

Comment: also when reading (the getter) range.formula <> range.value.

Comment: Also, if you want to use `R1C1` notation, it's actually not required to use it because you can achieve the same goal with `A1` notation. For instance: `Range("A1:A10").Formula = "=B1+C1"` is the same as `Range("A1:A10").Formula = "=RC[1]+RC[2]"` (note that when using `R1C1` formula, we can use `Formula` as well as `FormulaR1C1` - it's again twist of Excel).

Comment: You will find issues when making references to other sheets, or if the cell isn’t formatted correctly for the data you want to go in. Good practice would have you only use .Value when entering a Value, but using .Formula when you are inputting any Formula (Sorry, I know that last bit is obvious)

Comment: It's called **overhead**. The compiler and platform attempts to correct any stupid mistakes that dumbass, lazy 'programmers' make. The more overhead that is built into the compiler, the slower the programming language. Try the same in C or Assembler.

Comment: @JohnyL There are cases where Excel can't correctly guess that you are using R1C1 notation if you use the `Formula` property - e.g. `Range("A1").Formula = "=RC2+RC3"` and `Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC2+RC3"` give different results

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, that's why I called it a twist, but it's *always* better to be explicit.

Comment: @YowE3K Your example with `Formula` gave incorrect result (more accurately, the one we didn't expect), because `RC2` and `RC3` are *valid* sheet cells.

Comment: IMO - Using `Range("F3") = "=sum(b6+h9)"` and Excel resolving that as the real sum is a bug/'mistake' on Excel/VBA's part. Without using `Formula`, default is `.Value`, so I'd personally expect that line to resolve to the string `=sum(b6+h9)`.

Comment: @JohnyL Yes, that is why it is good to be explicit - in some cases Excel guesses your intentions incorrectly

Comment: @BruceWayne I just wish Excel would pop up an error message when users enter `=SUM(B6+H9)` saying "Don't be silly, what's the point in using SUM when you have only got a single, non-array, parameter" ;)

Comment: @BruceWayne - Another example of MS smarting you out.